# Moving a website and ftp

Tags: http, dom, web, ftp, hosting

101 for website and ftp:  Do anyone know the best web hosting site for a beginner?  Do ATT u-verse offer web hosting if you have their service?

I just want to keep this simple for a beginner.  I have seen commercials on go daddy and googled to see google have something.  Just need to upload files and put together a website.  I used Yahoo business in the past while taking classes in 2005 on internet programming and ".net".  I just checked the site today that I created.  My .com is still up and running.  It seems as though another company want me to move everything over as of November.  And I also have a problem that need to be resolved by posting my file so others can view it to help me resolve my problem because you can't do attachments in posts.  Here is what was said:

"..but may post a link (not shortened) to a site (no password/logon) that hosts a file..."

Thank you for your help in advance,
Ty

Answer (score 0):

You have many options for web hosting providers. I offer web hosting through my company but to keep this unbiased these are two popular options for web hosting.

1. [Godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/) is a very popular option for web hosting. You can get a shared server plan for about five dollars a month. They will give you FTP access to the server and even provide technical support in case you have any issues. Once you have the webhosting service account live you may change the nameservers to point to your server and then upload your website files to the www/username dir or the public_html/username dir.
2. [AWS Free Tiers](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_hv_b&sc_content=aws_core_e_control_wia&sc_detail=aws&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=wia_q4_2015_control_78924631962&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!78924631962!e!!g!!aws&ef_id=VmMtagAABGPSMD8Z:20151213162311:s) Option two is free if you do not use to much of the server resources. But if you go over it only charges you for what you use. `AWS` is a service through amazon that allows you to create instances of virtual private servers. It is a lot harder to configure but the tradeoff is that it is usually less expensive. Most of the time if you do not have a lot going on it is free.

[FTP File Zilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is my favorite ftp. It is free and there are lots of resources online showing you how to use it. [File Zilla Tutorial](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_Client_Tutorial_(en))

If you are having problems with your current website please post a new question with a detailed description of the problem and an example of your doe as well as what you have tried to fix it. I am sure someone would be happy to help you.

Comment: No problem with my current website except Yahoo business don't exist anymore.  I checked AWS.  It wants me to add credit card information.  I didn't go to Godaddy.  I think FTP File Zilla answer for sharing the document requires the other person to use it to retrieve the file.  I have some questions:

Why is google not in the top 10?
What is the difference between Google Domains and Google Cloud?
Are there any of them that don't require a credit card?

Thanks,
Ty

Comment: Google domains is just new. I love google but at the end of the day I just prefer to use stuff that has been around for a while so I can easily find documentation for it when I need some help. As far as for free hosting AWS is free unless you use more than the free resources. meaning people are coming to your site or your using a bunch of resources in development. If you search in google for free web hosting I was able to come up with some as low as .30c filezilla allows you to transfer files to a server. So you would get your server and connect file zilla to it then upload files to the server